# Angular2 inject a service from AppModule into dependent NgModule's component at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, service, dependency-injection, module

If I have:

`AppModule
    imports: [SubModule],
    providers: [AppProvidedService]`

and

`SubModule
    declarations: [SubComponent]`

and

`SubComponent
    constructor(appProvidedService: AppProvidedService){}`

I get:

`Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for SubComponent: (?).`

Basically, it is saying that AppProvidedService cannot be resolved by the injector.

How do you build an NgModule in such a way as to have it depend on a service that is created in an NgModule that depends on it?

I tried using OpaqueToken and interfaces, but I still have the same issue.  The SubModule just can't see what's coming from a parent module.

The end desire is to have a module that can take injections from the application that imported it.  That way, I can inject app-specific behavior into common components.

Comment: Is it just a typo? you are using `provides` instead of `providers` ?

Comment: This approach should work. I had few of these question mark issues moving to module approach, but was able to fix them all. Unfortunately, I don't remember how )) You need to  put right thins in right place.And yes, fix all typos too ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  It does require OpaqueTokens.

First, provide an interface and OpaqueToken for the interface (app-provided.service.interface:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from "@angular/core";

export interface AppProvidedServiceInterface {
    ...
}

export const SERVICE_INTERFACE = new OpaqueToken("AppProvidedServiceInterface");
```

In AppModule's providers:

```
    /*
     * Injection of app-specific behavior into a common module without hard dependencies:
     *
     * This is how you inject a service into a module that is imported
     * and prevent that module from having a hard dependency on the actual
     * implementation.  Use an interface with an OpaqueToken. Then the
     * component that needs it imports it and uses the AppInjector to get the
     * instance.
     */
    {
        provide: SERVICE_INTERFACE,
        useFactory: () => {
            return new AppProvidedService();
        }
    }
```

And in bootstrap get the reference to the app injector and store it... (we use a simple singleton class called AppInjector (source at the end of answer)):

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.then((appRef: NgModuleRef<AppComponent>) => {
        AppInjector.getInstance().setInjector(appRef.injector);
    },
    error => console.log(error) // tslint:disable-line
);
```

Then, in your SubModule, in the class where you want to use the injected thing, you must get use the injector to find the class based on the OpaqueToken (sub.component.ts):

```
// DO NOT REFERENCE A CONCRETE SERVICE!
private appProvidedService: AppProvidedServiceInterface;

constructor(/* can't inject it here */) {
    // Get the app-specific behavior from the service injected in the application module.
    this.appProvidedService = AppInjector.getInstance().getInjector().get(SERVICE_INTERFACE);
}
```

Now, your SubModule has a reference to an interface, not a concrete implementation and AppModule can inject the desired behavior through `providers: []`!

AppInjector singleton:

```
import { Injector } from "@angular/core";

export class AppInjector {
    private static instance: AppInjector;
    private injector: Injector;

    constructor() {
        // throw new Error("Singleton - can't instantiate.");        
    }

    public static getInstance() {
        if (!AppInjector.instance) {
            AppInjector.instance = new AppInjector();
        }

        return AppInjector.instance;
    }

    public setInjector(injector: Injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    public getInjector(): Injector {
        return this.injector;
    }
}
```